# Python request.get error on Wikipedia image URL

Tags: python, python-requests, wikipedia

Requests.get() does not seem to be returning the expected bytes for Wikipedia image URLs, such as *https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/20100726_Kalamitsi_Beach_Ionian_Sea_Lefkada_island_Greece.jpg*:

```
import wikipedia
import requests

page = wikipedia.page("beach")
first_image_link = page.images[0]
req = requests.get(first_image_link)
req.content

b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<title>Wikimedia Error</title>\n<style>\n*...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most websites block requests that come in without a valid browser as a User-Agent. Wikimedia is one such.

```
import requests
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
res = requests.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/20100726_Kalamitsi_Beach_Ionian_Sea_Lefkada_island_Greece.jpg', headers=headers)
res.content
```

which will give you expected output

[image]

Comment: From https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy -"Do not copy a browser's user agent for your bot, as bot-like behavior with a browser's user agent will be assumed malicious." Be careful about adding a browser user agent to your requests when not accessing from a browser.

Answer (score 2):

I typed your code and it seems to be an *"Error: 403, Forbidden."*. Wikipedia requires a [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Use_in_HTTP) header in the request.

```
import wikipedia
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0'
}

page = wikipedia.page("beach")
first_image_link = page.images[0]
req = requests.get(first_image_link, headers=headers, stream=True)
req.content
```

For the user agent, you should probably supply something a bit more descriptive than the placeholder I use in my example. Maybe the name of your script, or just the word "script" or something like that.
I tested it and it works fine. You will get back the image as you are expecting.